# Why can't the 3-type of $S^2$ be delooped?

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, homotopy-theory, groupoids

In 2.2 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1303.4669.pdf), the argument runs through the fact that the 3-type of $S^2$ cannot be delooped. Why not?

I understand that this is probably a fairly basic fact of homotopy theory (hence neither that paper nor [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9810059.pdf), which it cites, providing an explanation or source for the fact). All I know of homotopy stems from studying higher categories & groupoids, so I'm weak on the basics. Unfortunately, my google-fu has failed me, and I haven't been able to find a source that discusses why the 3-type of the 2-sphere cannot be delooped. I'd appreciate a pointer to an appropriate text, and I'd appreciate a quick explanation of why this should be so even more.

Comment: I'm not seeing where the argument uses that claim. Instead, I see the claim that the 3-type of $S^2$ is not an infinite loop space.

Comment: Short answer: the presence of non-trivial Whitehead products in $\pi_3S^2$ obstructs the existence of a H-space structure on the 3-type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $X$ denote the $3$-type of $S^2$.  The only nontrivial homotopy groups of $X$ are $\pi_2(X)\cong\mathbb{Z}$ and $\pi_3(X)\cong\mathbb{Z}$.  Suppose $X$ could be delooped, so there is a connected space $Y$ such that $X\simeq \Omega Y$.  The only nontrivial homotopy groups of $Y$ would be $\pi_3(Y)\cong\mathbb{Z}$ and $\pi_4(Y)\cong\mathbb{Z}$.

Now a homotopy type with only two nontrivial homotopy groups $\pi_m(X)\cong A$ and $\pi_n(X)\cong B$ ($n>m$) is classified by its $k$-invariant, a cohomology class in $H^{n+1}(K(A,m);B)$.  Explicitly, such a cohomology class corresponds to a map $K(A,m)\to K(B,n+1)$ (up to homotopy) and then you take the homotopy fiber of this map to get your space.

So, our delooping $Y$ would be classified by a class in $H^5(K(\mathbb{Z},3);\mathbb{Z})$.  Now it happens that $H^5(K(\mathbb{Z},3);\mathbb{Z})$ is trivial (you can compute the cohomology of $K(\mathbb{Z},3)$ from the cohomology of $K(\mathbb{Z},2)=\mathbb{CP}^\infty$ using the Serre spectral sequence, for instance), so the $k$-invariant of $Y$ is trivial, so actually $Y\simeq K(\mathbb{Z},3)\times K(\mathbb{Z},4)$.  It then follows that $X\simeq K(\mathbb{Z},2)\times K(\mathbb{Z},3)$.  But this is false: it would imply, for instance, that $H_3(X;\mathbb{Z})$ is nontrivial (since $H_3(K(\mathbb{Z},3);\mathbb{Z})\cong\mathbb{Z}$), but $H_3(X;\mathbb{Z})\cong H_3(S^2;\mathbb{Z})$ is trivial.

Comment: Thanks! Given that all I know of homotopy stems from studying higher categories & groupoids, I cannot yet make heads or tails of this. Can you point me towards a resource that will sketch out the claims made here (such as what a k-invariant is, why a h-type w/ only 2 non-trivial h-groups is classified by one, etc.)? Alternatively, is there a rephrasing of this fact in the language of category/groupoid theory?

Comment: You can find most if not all of this somewhere in most graduate-level algebraic topology textbooks.  For instance, everything used here except for the computation of $H^5(K(\mathbb{Z},3);\mathbb{Z})$ can be found in Chapter 4 of Hatcher's _Algebraic Topology_.  This statement really is fundamentally a computational statement so I wouldn't expect to be able to understand it without a good understanding of some of the basic computational methods in homotopy theory.

Comment: @Nate It is possible to express the non-existence of such a delooping in terms of the non-existence of a monoidal structure on a 3-groupoid, or even in terms of the impossibility of upgrading a braided monoidal structure on a groupoid to be symmetric monoidal, but to actually prove this non-existence one needs to calculate some cohomology. This is in principle an integral part of category/groupoid theory, but in practice is worked out mainly in topology books.

Comment: @KevinCarlson thanks. Do you know offhand of a particularly simple resource that calculates the cohomology to show one of those three claims?

Comment: @Nate No, nothing much better than what Eric says.

Answer (score 2):

You know, the $h$-space approach suggested by Tyrone and by the paper may feel more elementary, as it doesn't need Eilenberg-Mac Lane spaces, spectral sequences, or any cohomology.

Let's also let $X$ be the $3$-type of $S^2$. If $X$ were equivalent to a loop space $\Omega Y$, then concatenation of loops would make $X$ into an $h$-space, in fact an $A_\infty$-space, though that's more than we need. An $h$-space is just a space admitting a multiplication map which admits a unit up to homotopy, so this should be easy to verify directly.

Next, you need to know that there is something called a Whitehead product, a bilinear mapping $\pi_{n_1}(X)\times \pi_{n_2}(X)\to \pi_{n_1+n_2-1}(X)$, which is defined using the natural map $S^{n_1+n_2-1}\to S^{n_1}\vee S^{n_2}$ which is the attaching map in the cell structure on $S^{n_1}\times S^{n_2}$ that has a $0$-cell, an $n_1$-cell, an $n_2$-cell, and an $n_1+n_2$-cell. These Whitehead products should in principle be explainable in terms of higher groupoid theory, but of course nobody has a really workable definition of higher groupoid that's not more or less based on topological spaces or simplicial sets, so this is difficult to understand in a dramatically different way. Samelson products are in principle a bit more algebraic.

OK, so once we have Whitehead products, it's an exercise to prove that every $h$-space has trivial Whitehead products (indeed, it's Hatcher 4.2.37.) The idea is to show that every map $(\alpha,\beta):S^{n_1}\vee S^{n_2}\to X$ extends to $S^{n_1}\times S^{n_2}$, which is the cofiber of the attaching map that defines the Whitehead product. This implies the Whitehead products are trivial because cofiber sequences of spaces are weak pushouts in the homotopy category, so mapping them into $X$ gives a weak pullback of pointed sets.

Such an extension $\gamma:S^{n_1}\times S^{n_2}\to X$, for $X$ an $h$-space whose base point is its unit $e$, is given simply by $\gamma(x,y)=\alpha(x)\beta(y)$, where the multiplication uses the $h$-space structure on $X$. $\gamma$ restricts to $\alpha$ and $\beta$ on $S^{n_1}\times \{*\}$ and $\{*\}\times S^{n_2}$ respectively, using the fact that multiplication with $e=\alpha(*)=\beta(*)$ is trivial. (In principle it's only homotopy trivial, but every $h$-space is homotopy equivalent to one with a strict unit.)

Comment: Thanks! This is closer to the sort of thing I was looking for. I have a sneaking suspicion that this fact should have a much simpler visualization. For instance, I was expecting someone to chime in saying something roughly like "If the 3-type of S^2 could be delooped, then its horizontal & vertical composition would commute. Now, consider the map which takes id to itself by wrapping around the globe. The vertical composition of this map with itself is not homotopic to its horizontal composition with itself, b/c <reason>. Also, if  it were, <geometric absurd consequence>."

Comment: Perhaps this fact just is very non-trivial, but I can't shake the feeling that it should have simple geometric consequences, without needing to invoke the whitehead products or the wedge sum or all that (which, at my current level of understanding, render all of this very difficult to visualize).

Comment: @Nate I admit to some sympathy with the feeling that the result is fundamental enough to need a prettier proof, and I'm not sure I have sufficient evidence that no such argument exists. I do have some-delooping has been an intensive area of study for over fifty years. On the other hand, few topologists and only lately have been in the habit of thinking of homotopy types as higher groupoids...

Comment: @Nate On the other hand there's no reason at all to be worried about a wedge sum. You just stick two spheres together.

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer to a different question which I can't find: when is X an H-space?

Let G = \pi_1(X) and H = \pi_2(X)
Interpret the Postnikov invariant beta  as a (homotopy class of maps)
K(G,1) to K(H,3)
Then X is an H-space if and only if beta is primitive
i.e. for m the multiplication on K(G,1)
if and only if m^* beta = beta \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes beta

In this special case of K(G,1)  K(H,3)
This is also sufficient for beta to be the looping of B beta \in H^4(BG,H)

More generally there is a result due to Art Copeland that if X is induced
by f :K(G,p) to K(H,q) with q  \geq p then X has an H-space structure if and only if
f represents a primitive class

Outside that range, things are more subtle

Not sure what you mean by H-group